# Why increasing audio gain doesn't work?

Tags: ios, openal

I'm using this line of code to set gain of sound source. I want to increase volume of sound to be loud, (like alarm in iOS), but if I try to set gain greater than 1.0 it doesn't effect.

In documentation it's said

```
/**
 * Indicate the gain (volume amplification) applied. 
 * Type:   ALfloat.
 * Range:  ]0.0-  ]
 * A value of 1.0 means un-attenuated/unchanged.
 * Each division by 2 equals an attenuation of -6dB.
 * Each multiplicaton with 2 equals an amplification of +6dB.
 * A value of 0.0 is meaningless with respect to a logarithmic
 *  scale; it is interpreted as zero volume - the channel
 *  is effectively disabled.
 */
#define AL_GAIN                                   0x100A

alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, 4.0f);//Set gain/volume  - 4.0f sounds the same as 1.0f gain
```

Am I doing something wrong?  If gain won't work, is there any other way to increase volume of sound.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of 1.0 means un-attenuated/unchanged. Thus, values above 1.0f are treated the same as 1.0f.

Comment: So - Each multiplicaton with 2 equals an amplification of +6dB, only works if it's less than 1?

Comment: Each division by 2 reduces the amplitude by 6 dB, and all above 1.0f is not leading to increased sound volume. Exactly. Probably the user has to change the volume of the device for louder output. At least for me it is the same with the alarm clock app.

Comment: Device sound is on maximum, but it still sounds not loud enough :( I won't accept answer now, might somebody has solution how to increase volume. Thanks for clarification +1.

Comment: How loud is your sound source, maybe you need to increase that before sending it to the speakers?